# Couchbase restore error

Tags: couchbase

server system: Ubuntu 10.04.2

Couchbase: 1.8.1

python: 2.7.3

back files: cbbackup ./default-data/default /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120705

restore: cbrestore -a default_20120705/default*

```
root@945f14b6-3015-4dac-b486-a8914a3f553d:~# cbrestore -a /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults*
Error on key 'sk_deviceHistory_F118C61C-8B30-4667-A7E2-2959836734BD': Memcached error #32:  Auth failure
Error on key 'sk_deviceHistory_F118C61C-8B30-4667-A7E2-2959836734BD': Memcached error #32:  Auth failure
Error on key 'sk_deviceHistory_F118C61C-8B30-4667-A7E2-2959836734BD': Memcached error #32:  Auth failure
Error on key 'sk_deviceHistory_F118C61C-8B30-4667-A7E2-2959836734BD': Memcached error #32:  Auth failure
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 cbrestore -a /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults*
root@945f14b6-3015-4dac-b486-a8914a3f553d:~# ps -ef|grep python
root       711   512  1 15:46 pts/2    00:00:00 python /opt/couchbase/lib/python/cbrestore -a /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults-0.mb /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults-1.mb /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults-2.mb /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults-3.mb
root       726   512  0 15:46 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
root@945f14b6-3015-4dac-b486-a8914a3f553d:~# kill -9 711
root@945f14b6-3015-4dac-b486-a8914a3f553d:~# ps -ef|grep python
root       729   512  0 15:47 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
[1]+  Killed                  cbrestore -a /data/Couchbase_backups/default_20120706/defaults*
root@945f14b6-3015-4dac-b486-a8914a3f553d:~# ps -ef|grep python
root       731   512  0 15:47 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
root@945f14b6-3015-4dac-b486-a8914a3f553d:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the -u BUCKET_NAME and -p BUCKET_PASSWORD parameters?  That way the cbrestore tool can successfully authenticate to the right bucket?

For more flag and usage, also, there's also the -h / --help parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ./cbbackup HOST:PORT ~/Documents/ -u ‘username’ -p ‘password‘ -b BUCKET_NAME
```

This works for me.